# What does [R0,R3] do in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm a beginner in assembly and I've already searched online for this question, but to no avail...

Recently I've been trying to disassemble a library used for a particular Android Application. After disassembling it with IDA Pro, I came across this subroutine:

```
MOVS    R3, 0x1AC
LDR     R0, [R0,R3]
BX      LR
```

I understand most of what's happening in these 3 lines, but I'm stuck at

```
LDR     R0, [R0,R3]
```

What does this line do exactly? Does it set the R0 to the value in R0 offset by R3?

Comment: In C syntax: `R0 = *(uint32*)(R0+R3);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> LDR     R0, [R0,R3]
>   What does this line do exactly

`R3` acts as an offset to the base address (`R0`). In other words, the effective address is `R0+R3`, and the value *loaded from that address* is written to `R0`.
See [the documentation for LDR/STR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/CIHGCADB.html).

The reason for not just using `LDR R0,[R0,#0x1AC]` is probably that this is Thumb code. The immediate offset for an `LDR/STR` in Thumb mode [is only 7 bits](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/CIHGJHED.html#CIHEHIHH) (5 bits shifted 2 bits to the left), and 0x1AC wouldn't fit in 7 bits. Hence the offset is placed in a register first.